# Center mesh at world origin in Babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs

I have a set of 3D face scan obj files I need to display, and I am looking to center each mesh in the world origin.

I have an example below with one of the actual meshes, but if you look, I just tweaked some numbers and rotated it to look right:

```
    mesh.position.x = .1;
    mesh.position.y = .46;
    mesh.position.z = 0;
    mesh.setPivotPoint(mesh.getBoundingInfo().boundingBox.center);
    mesh.rotate(BABYLON.Axis.Y, -(Math.PI / 2), BABYLON.Space.WORLD);
    mesh.rotate(BABYLON.Axis.X, -(Math.PI / 2), BABYLON.Space.WORLD);
```

I enabled the bounding box and that is correct.

**How can I render each one centered on the origin without magic numbers?**

Thanks!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas"); // Get the canvas element
var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true); 



var createScene = function () {
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    
    scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color3.FromInts(1, 1, 1);


    //Adding a light
    var light = new BABYLON.PointLight("Omni", new BABYLON.Vector3(20, 20, 100), scene);

    //Adding an Arc Rotate Camera
    // var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 3, 0, .7, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", -(Math.PI/2), Math.PI/2, .5, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);

    // camera.panningAxis = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    camera.attachControl(canvas, false);



    BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("" , "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n4gwsdn9en6pi86/", "test_ms_simple.obj", scene, function (newMeshes) {
        
        camera.target = BABYLON.Vector3.Zero();
        // var mesh = newMeshes[0].getChildMeshes()[0];
        var mesh = newMeshes[0];
        mesh.showBoundingBox = true;
    
        mesh.position.x = .1;
        mesh.position.y = .46;
        mesh.position.z = 0;
        mesh.setPivotPoint(mesh.getBoundingInfo().boundingBox.center);
        mesh.rotate(BABYLON.Axis.Y, -(Math.PI / 2), BABYLON.Space.WORLD);
        mesh.rotate(BABYLON.Axis.X, -(Math.PI / 2), BABYLON.Space.WORLD);

        camera.minZ = 0;
        camera.wheelPrecision = 500;

    });

  



    // Move the light with the camera
    scene.registerBeforeRender(function () {
        light.position = camera.position;
    });
    // showAxis(10);
    return scene;
}



 
      var scene = createScene(); //Call the createScene function

      // Register a render loop to repeatedly render the scene
      engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
              scene.render();
              
      });

      // Watch for browser/canvas resize events
      window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
              engine.resize();
      });


function showAxis(size) {
    var makeTextPlane = function(text, color, size) {
        var dynamicTexture = new BABYLON.DynamicTexture("DynamicTexture", 50, scene, true);
        dynamicTexture.hasAlpha = true;
        dynamicTexture.drawText(text, 5, 40, "bold 36px Arial", color , "transparent", true);
        var plane = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("TextPlane", size, scene, true);
        plane.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("TextPlaneMaterial", scene);
        plane.material.backFaceCulling = false;
        plane.material.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
        plane.material.diffuseTexture = dynamicTexture;
    return plane;
     };
    var axisX = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("axisX", [ 
      BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), new BABYLON.Vector3(size, 0, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3(size * 0.95, 0.05 * size, 0), 
      new BABYLON.Vector3(size, 0, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3(size * 0.95, -0.05 * size, 0)
      ], scene);
    axisX.color = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0);
    var xChar = makeTextPlane("X", "red", size / 10);
    xChar.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0.9 * size, -0.05 * size, 0);
    var axisY = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("axisY", [
        BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), new BABYLON.Vector3(0, size, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3( -0.05 * size, size * 0.95, 0), 
        new BABYLON.Vector3(0, size, 0), new BABYLON.Vector3( 0.05 * size, size * 0.95, 0)
        ], scene);
    axisY.color = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0);
    var yChar = makeTextPlane("Y", "green", size / 10);
    yChar.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0.9 * size, -0.05 * size);
    var axisZ = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateLines("axisZ", [
        BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, size), new BABYLON.Vector3( 0 , -0.05 * size, size * 0.95),
        new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, size), new BABYLON.Vector3( 0, 0.05 * size, size * 0.95)
        ], scene);
    axisZ.color = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 1);
    var zChar = makeTextPlane("Z", "blue", size / 10);
    zChar.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0.05 * size, 0.9 * size);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>
<script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/loaders/babylon.objFileLoader.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="renderCanvas" width=350 height=350>
```